# How can I fix this mysqli_fetch_array error?

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, echo

I have the following code:

```
echo(mysqli_num_rows($mysqlData));
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($mysqlData, MYSQLI_BOTH);
echo(mysqli_num_rows($mysqlData));
echo(gettype($row));
echo($row[1]);
```

Which produces the following:

```
1
1
array
(produces no output)
```

I think there are a couple issues here. The # of rows should be decremented by 1 each time mysqli_fetch_array is used but that does not seem to be the case. Also the `$row` array seems to be an array but does not seem to contain any data. I've used some associative keys that should work bur do not show any data. Interestingly, using `echo(count($row));` at the end of the above code block produces 20 which is far more than the number of coulmns for the used table in my database. Any help would be super! Thanks!

Comment: Why should the number of rows be decremented? It's the number of rows __returned by the query__, not the number that you've not yet fetched

Comment: use `echo ($row[[column_name]])` to echo the contents.

Comment: Is it conceivably possible that $row[1] is an empty string, or a Boolean false? var_dump() will tell you lots more than echo

Comment: `echo(count($row)); ` is a count of both enumerated and associative elements in the $row array because you're using MYSQLI_BOTH.... so precisely double the number of columns in the actual database table (or at least your select list)

Comment: @MarkBaker I think decremented was poor wording. My understanding of mysqli_fetch_array was that it removed one of the rows returned by the query. Is this not the case?

Comment: No, it isn't the case.... it returns a single result, and moves the internal resource pointer onto the next result in the result set, ready for the next fetch, it doesn't "remove" anything.... the records that you've already fetched are still available, and you can always reset that internal pointer using [data_seek](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.data-seek.php)

Comment: @MarkBaker ok thanks i think i may as well remove the question